# How to make RTL layout for Highcharts Stock chart?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, nuxt.js, right-to-left

I have NUXT JS Project installed with `"highcharts": "^10.1.0"` package. I created three plugins 1. highcharts.js 2. default.js 3. dark.js.

**highcharts.js**

```
import Stock from 'highcharts/modules/stock';

if (typeof Highchart === 'object') {
    Stock(Highchart);
}

export default ( { app }, inject ) => {
    inject('highChart', Highchart);
}
```

**default.js**

```
export default {
    colors: [
      "#7cb5ec",
      "#434348",
      "#90ed7d",
      "#f7a35c",
      "#8085e9",
      "#f15c80",
      "#e4d354",
      "#2b908f",
      "#f45b5b",
      "#91e8e1"
    ],
    symbols: ["circle", "diamond", "square", "triangle", "triangle-down"],
    lang: {
      loading: "Loading...",
      months: [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
      ],
      shortMonths: [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec"
      ],
      weekdays: [
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday"
      ],
      decimalPoint: ".",
      numericSymbols: ["k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"],
      resetZoom: "Reset zoom",
      resetZoomTitle: "Reset zoom level 1:1",
      thousandsSep: " "
    },
    global: {},
    time: { timezoneOffset: 0, useUTC: true },
    chart: {
      styledMode: false,
      borderRadius: 0,
      colorCount: 10,
      defaultSeriesType: "line",
      ignoreHiddenSeries: true,
      spacing: [10, 10, 15, 10],
      resetZoomButton: {
        theme: { zIndex: 6 },
        position: { align: "right", x: -10, y: 10 }
      },
      width: null,
      height: null,
      borderColor: "#335cad",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      plotBorderColor: "#cccccc",
      style: {
        fontFamily:
          '"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
          direction: 'rtl'
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: "Chart title",
      align: "center",
      margin: 15,
      widthAdjust: -44,
      style: {
        color: "#333333",
        textTransform: "",
        fontSize: "1.25rem"
      }
    },
    subtitle: { 
      text: "", 
      align: "center", 
      widthAdjust: -44, 
      style: {
        color: "#909090"
      } 
    },
    caption: { margin: 15, text: "", align: "left", verticalAlign: "bottom" },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: {
          enabledThreshold: 2,
          lineColor: "#ffffff",
          lineWidth: 0,
          radius: 4,
          states: {
            normal: { animation: true },
            hover: {
              animation: { duration: 50 },
              enabled: true,
              radiusPlus: 2,
              lineWidthPlus: 1
            },
            select: { fillColor: "#cccccc", lineColor: "#000000", lineWidth: 2 }
          }
        },
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          align: "center",
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        cropThreshold: 300,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: 0,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: { size: 10, opacity: 0.25 }
          },
          select: { animation: { duration: 0 } },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: true,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "x"
      },
      area: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: {
          enabledThreshold: 2,
          lineColor: "#ffffff",
          lineWidth: 0,
          radius: 4,
          states: {
            normal: { animation: true },
            hover: {
              animation: { duration: 50 },
              enabled: true,
              radiusPlus: 2,
              lineWidthPlus: 1
            },
            select: { fillColor: "#cccccc", lineColor: "#000000", lineWidth: 2 }
          }
        },
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          align: "center",
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        cropThreshold: 300,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: 0,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: { size: 10, opacity: 0.25 }
          },
          select: { animation: { duration: 0 } },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: true,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "x",
        threshold: 0
      },
      spline: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: {
          enabledThreshold: 2,
          lineColor: "#ffffff",
          lineWidth: 0,
          radius: 4,
          states: {
            normal: { animation: true },
            hover: {
              animation: { duration: 50 },
              enabled: true,
              radiusPlus: 2,
              lineWidthPlus: 1
            },
            select: { fillColor: "#cccccc", lineColor: "#000000", lineWidth: 2 }
          }
        },
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          align: "center",
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        cropThreshold: 300,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: 0,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: { size: 10, opacity: 0.25 }
          },
          select: { animation: { duration: 0 } },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: true,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "x"
      },
      areaspline: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: {
          enabledThreshold: 2,
          lineColor: "#ffffff",
          lineWidth: 0,
          radius: 4,
          states: {
            normal: { animation: true },
            hover: {
              animation: { duration: 50 },
              enabled: true,
              radiusPlus: 2,
              lineWidthPlus: 1
            },
            select: { fillColor: "#cccccc", lineColor: "#000000", lineWidth: 2 }
          }
        },
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          align: "center",
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        cropThreshold: 300,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: 0,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: { size: 10, opacity: 0.25 }
          },
          select: { animation: { duration: 0 } },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: true,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "x",
        threshold: 0
      },
      column: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: null,
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          x: 0
        },
        cropThreshold: 50,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: null,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: false,
            brightness: 0.1
          },
          select: {
            animation: { duration: 0 },
            color: "#cccccc",
            borderColor: "#000000"
          },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: false,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "x",
        borderRadius: 0,
        centerInCategory: false,
        groupPadding: 0.2,
        pointPadding: 0.1,
        minPointLength: 0,
        startFromThreshold: true,
        tooltip: { distance: 6 },
        threshold: 0,
        borderColor: "#ffffff"
      },
      bar: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: null,
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          x: 0
        },
        cropThreshold: 50,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: null,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: false,
            brightness: 0.1
          },
          select: {
            animation: { duration: 0 },
            color: "#cccccc",
            borderColor: "#000000"
          },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: false,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "x",
        borderRadius: 0,
        centerInCategory: false,
        groupPadding: 0.2,
        pointPadding: 0.1,
        minPointLength: 0,
        startFromThreshold: true,
        tooltip: { distance: 6 },
        threshold: 0,
        borderColor: "#ffffff"
      },
      scatter: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: {
          enabledThreshold: 2,
          lineColor: "#ffffff",
          lineWidth: 0,
          radius: 4,
          states: {
            normal: { animation: true },
            hover: {
              animation: { duration: 50 },
              enabled: true,
              radiusPlus: 2,
              lineWidthPlus: 1
            },
            select: { fillColor: "#cccccc", lineColor: "#000000", lineWidth: 2 }
          },
          enabled: true
        },
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          align: "center",
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        cropThreshold: 300,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: 0,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: { size: 10, opacity: 0.25 }
          },
          select: { animation: { duration: 0 } },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: true,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "xy",
        jitter: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat:
            '<span style="color:{point.color}">●</span> <span style="font-size: 10px"> {series.name}</span><br/>',
          pointFormat: "x: <b>{point.x}</b><br/>y: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>"
        }
      },
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: false,
        crisp: true,
        showCheckbox: false,
        animation: { duration: 1000 },
        events: {},
        marker: null,
        point: { events: {} },
        dataLabels: {
          animation: {},
          align: "center",
          defer: true,
          padding: 5,
          style: {
            fontSize: "11px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "contrast",
            textOutline: "1px contrast"
          },
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          allowOverlap: true,
          connectorPadding: 5,
          connectorShape: "fixedOffset",
          crookDistance: "70%",
          distance: 30,
          enabled: true,
          softConnector: true
        },
        cropThreshold: 300,
        opacity: 1,
        pointRange: 0,
        softThreshold: true,
        states: {
          normal: { animation: true },
          hover: {
            animation: { duration: 50 },
            lineWidthPlus: 1,
            marker: {},
            halo: { size: 10, opacity: 0.25 },
            brightness: 0.1
          },
          select: { animation: { duration: 0 } },
          inactive: { animation: { duration: 50 }, opacity: 0.2 }
        },
        stickyTracking: false,
        turboThreshold: 1000,
        findNearestPointBy: "x",
        center: [null, null],
        clip: false,
        colorByPoint: true,
        ignoreHiddenPoint: true,
        inactiveOtherPoints: true,
        legendType: "point",
        size: null,
        showInLegend: false,
        slicedOffset: 10,
        tooltip: { followPointer: true },
        borderColor: "#ffffff",
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      candlestick: {
        lineColor: 'black',
        upLineColor: 'black', // docs
        upColor: 'black'
      } 
    },
    labels: { style: { position: "absolute", color: "#333333" } },
    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      rtl: true,
      align: "center",
      alignColumns: true,
      layout: "horizontal",
      borderColor: "#999999",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      borderRadius: 0,
      navigation: { activeColor: "#003399", inactiveColor: "#cccccc" },
      itemStyle: {
        color: "#333333",
        cursor: "pointer",
        fontSize: "12px",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textOverflow: "ellipsis"
      },
      itemHoverStyle: { color: "#000000" },
      itemHiddenStyle: { color: "#cccccc" },
      shadow: false,
      itemCheckboxStyle: { position: "absolute", width: "13px", height: "13px" },
      squareSymbol: true,
      symbolPadding: 5,
      verticalAlign: "bottom",
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      title: { style: { fontWeight: "bold" } }
    },
    loading: {
      labelStyle: { fontWeight: "bold", position: "relative", top: "45%" },
      style: {
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        opacity: 0.5,
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      outside: true,
      split: true,
      enabled: true,
      animation: true,
      borderRadius: 3,
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L",
        second: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S",
        minute: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M",
        hour: "%A, %b %e, %H:%M",
        day: "%A, %b %e, %Y",
        week: "Week from %A, %b %e, %Y",
        month: "%B %Y",
        year: "%Y"
      },
      footerFormat: "",
      padding: 8,
      snap: 10,
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">{point.key}</span><br/>',
      pointFormat:
        '<span style="color:{point.color}">●</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
      backgroundColor: "rgba(247,247,247,0.85)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      shadow: true,
      style: {
        color: "#333333",
        cursor: "default",
        fontSize: "12px",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap"
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: true,
      href: "https://www.highcharts.com?credits",
      position: { align: "right", x: -10, verticalAlign: "bottom", y: -5 },
      style: { cursor: "pointer", color: "#999999", fontSize: "9px" },
      text: "Highcharts.com"
    },
  
    // It'e needed to set additional options from out of the default theme,
    // because Dark theme is adding the new properties not included within
    // default theme
  
    xAxis: {
      gridLineColor: "#D8D8D8",
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: "#606060"
        }
      },
      lineColor: "#C0D0E0",
      minorGridLineColor: "#e0e0e0",
      tickColor: "#C0D0E0",
      title: {
        style: {
          color: "#707070"
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineColor: "#D8D8D8",
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: "#606060"
        }
      },
      lineColor: "#C0D0E0",
      minorGridLineColor: "#e0e0e0",
      tickColor: "#C0D0E0",
      tickWidth: 0,
      title: {
        style: {
          color: "#707070"
        }
      }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      buttonTheme: {
        fill: "#f7f7f7",
        stroke: "#000000",
        style: {
          color: "#000000"
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: "#e6ebf5",
            stroke: "#000000",
            style: {
              color: "black"
            }
          },
          select: {
            fill: "#e6ebf5",
            stroke: "#000000",
            style: {
              color: "black"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      inputBoxBorderColor: "#CCC",
      inputStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: "black"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        color: "black"
      }
    },
  };
```

**dark.js**

```
export default {
    colors: [
      "#2b908f",
      "#90ee7e",
      "#f45b5b",
      "#7798BF",
      "#aaeeee",
      "#ff0066",
      "#eeaaee",
      "#55BF3B",
      "#DF5353",
      "#7798BF",
      "#aaeeee"
    ],
    chart: {
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
        stops: [
          [0, "#1B1B1B"],
          [1, "#1B1B1B"]
        ]
      },
      style: {
        fontFamily: "'Unica One', sans-serif",
        direction: 'rtl'
      },
      plotBorderColor: "#606063"
    },
    title: {
      style: {
        color: "#E0E0E3",
        textTransform: "uppercase",
        fontSize: "1.25rem"
      }
    },
    subtitle: {
      style: {
        color: "#E0E0E3",
        textTransform: "uppercase"
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      gridLineColor: "#707073",
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: "#E0E0E3"
        }
      },
      lineColor: "#707073",
      minorGridLineColor: "#505053",
      tickColor: "#707073",
      title: {
        style: {
          color: "#A0A0A3"
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineColor: "#707073",
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: "#E0E0E3"
        }
      },
      lineColor: "#707073",
      minorGridLineColor: "#505053",
      tickColor: "#707073",
      tickWidth: 1,
      title: {
        style: {
          color: "#A0A0A3"
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      outside: true,
      split: true,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)",
      style: {
        color: "#F0F0F0"
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          color: "#F0F0F3",
          style: {
            fontSize: "13px"
          }
        },
        marker: {
          lineColor: "#333"
        }
      },
      boxplot: {
        fillColor: "#505053"
      },
      candlestick: {
        lineColor: "white",
        upLineColor: 'white',
        upColor: 'white'
      },
      errorbar: {
        color: "white"
      }
    },
    legend: {
      rtl: true,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      itemStyle: {
        color: "#E0E0E3"
      },
      itemHoverStyle: {
        color: "#FFF"
      },
      itemHiddenStyle: {
        color: "#606063"
      },
      title: {
        style: {
          color: "#C0C0C0"
        }
      }
    },
    credits: {
      style: {
        color: "#666"
      }
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: "#707073"
      }
    },
    drilldown: {
      activeAxisLabelStyle: {
        color: "#F0F0F3"
      },
      activeDataLabelStyle: {
        color: "#F0F0F3"
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
        symbolStroke: "#DDDDDD",
        theme: {
          fill: "#505053"
        }
      }
    },
    // scroll charts
    rangeSelector: {
      buttonTheme: {
        fill: "#505053",
        stroke: "#000000",
        style: {
          color: "#CCC"
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: "#707073",
            stroke: "#000000",
            style: {
              color: "white"
            }
          },
          select: {
            fill: "#000003",
            stroke: "#000000",
            style: {
              color: "white"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      inputBoxBorderColor: "#505053",
      inputStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#333",
        color: "silver"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        color: "silver"
      }
    },
    navigator: {
      handles: {
        backgroundColor: "#666",
        borderColor: "#AAA"
      },
      outlineColor: "#CCC",
      maskFill: "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)",
      series: {
        color: "#7798BF",
        lineColor: "#A6C7ED"
      },
      xAxis: {
        gridLineColor: "#505053"
      }
    },
    scrollbar: {
      barBackgroundColor: "#808083",
      barBorderColor: "#808083",
      buttonArrowColor: "#CCC",
      buttonBackgroundColor: "#606063",
      buttonBorderColor: "#606063",
      rifleColor: "#FFF",
      trackBackgroundColor: "#404043",
      trackBorderColor: "#404043"
    }
  };
```

**Page _typ/_uisin/_wkn/index.vue**

```
<div id="container" ref="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px">
<script>
  import darkTheme from '../../../../plugins/dark'
  import defaultTheme from "../../../../plugins/default";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null,
      chartOptions: {
          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4,
            allButtonsEnabled: true
          },
          title: {
              text: null,
              // align: 'left'
          },
          subtitle: {
              text: 'Barriere=110 Euro, Bonuslevel=160 Euro',
              // align: 'left'
          },
          navigator: {
              enabled: true
          },
          yAxis: [
              {
                labels: {
                    align: 'left'
                },
                height: "80%",
                resize: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
              },
              {
                labels: {
                    align: 'left'
                },
                top: "80%",
                height: "20%",
                offset: 0,
              },
          ],
          credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
          series: [
              {
                  type: 'candlestick',
                  color: '#000',
                  upColor: '#fff',
                  name: 'Apple',
                  data: null
              },
              {
                  name: null,
                  data: null
              }
          ]
      }
    }
  },

if (this.$refs.container) {
  this.chart = this.$highChart.stockChart("container", this.chartOptions);
}
</script>
```

here in this chart i want make it RTL support. so how can i do that? i implement all the solution of search.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You need to adjust chart layout manually for internalization, more you can read at [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization#internationalization). Additionally you can have a look at this [post](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=45743#p163288) from Highcharts forum.

Comment: I have used @SebastianHajdus comment links answered and now working.

Comment: Could you prepare a simplified example with your config? When you stuck which part of chart do you need to fit into RTL languages?

Comment: i want to fit stock chart as given in index page code.

Comment: Please use online [demo](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#online-demos) like template to put your chart config at to the example, that will help me fit your options in RTL language.